# How to get 'Scripted Field' value using 'SQL for Confluence'?

Tags: sql, jira, confluence, scriptedfield

Is there a way to get the content of "Scripted Field" using SQL query
(the `filedtypekey` is `com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner:scripted-field`)

the name of the field can be listed using the query

```
SELECT 
*
FROM customfield 

WHERE cfname ='FiledName'
```

but trying to get it's value using the query bellow fails

```
SELECT 
*
FROM customfield 
JOIN customfieldvalue
ON
customfieldvalue.customfield=customfield.id

WHERE cfname ='FiledName'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get value of scripted field through a database request. It doesn't stores to database.